# Time data not matching format, although in reality it does match it

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've been trying to convert a column of a csv file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DNR07/CovidPredDatasets/main/covid_19_data.csv) to date time format using pandas.to_datetime() .
I've renamed the Observation date to just Date.
But when I use the aforementioned function I keep getting an error regarding the format of date time.
My exact code is:

```
c19_url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DNR07/CovidPredDatasets/main/covid_19_data.csv"
c19=requests.get(c19_url).content
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(tr.decode('utf-8')))
df.rename(columns={'ObservationDate':'Date','Province/State':'Province_State',
                   'Country/Region':'Country_Region','Confirmed':'ConfirmedCases',
                   'Deaths':'Fatalities'},inplace=True)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Now if you look at the CSV file, you can see that the format is
%m/%d/%Y, then why is the format in the error changing?
Error:
ValueError: time data '2020-01-22' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)

Where have I gone wong?

Comment: If I run this code myself (but changing 'tr' to 'c19') in the read_csv() call, the code works fine. I am using pandas 1.2.4. requests 2.25.1 and python 3.7 on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Should try:

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: But why is the format changing? If you look at the CSV file, the format is m/d/Y.

Comment: Check what type df['Date'] contains before you try to call to_datetime(). eg print(df.head()). I suspect that your version of read_csv() working on an input stream is doing some date conversion. If I save your csv file, and load it using read_csv(filename) then the date appears in the df as '01/22/2020', and the to_datetime() works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually was with the following line of code:

`df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(tr.decode('utf-8')))`

It works if you replace c19 with tr.
I made a silly mistake....